# For what $p$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt n\bigl(\frac 1 {\sqrt n}\bigr)^p$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> For what $p$ does $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt n\left(\frac 1 {\sqrt n}\right)^p$ converges?

I can brute force it and find that it's $p\ge 4$ but how do I find it with algebra?

Is it by solving $\frac {\sqrt n} {(\sqrt n)^p}<\frac 1 n$ for $p$? (I'm getting $\frac{ln(n\sqrt n)}{ln(\sqrt n)}<p$ which I don't know how to solve so I assume it's wrong)

Comment: Whoops, forgot to remove the displaystyle, thanks dustin.

Comment: You'll find that $p\geq 4$ leaves out (infinitely) many answers to the questions as well.

Comment: What you are getting is not wrong. By the law of logarithms we have $\frac{\log(n\sqrt{n})}{\log(\sqrt{n})} = \frac{\log(n^{3/2})}{\log(n^{1/2})} = \frac{(3/2)\log(n)}{(1/2)\log(n)}  = 3$ (which is the correct answer, not $4$).

Comment: Damn, I need to remind myself of log laws, thanks @Winther.

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic yeah, I assumed wrongly $p\in \mathbb N$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is $\sum {1\over {n^{{p-1\over 2}}}}$. Now you have a p-series.